# Balance of token not appearing in my wallet (Ethereun ERC20)

Tags: wallets, balances

I transferred AAA Tokens to my own wallet deposit which is under Network Ethereum ERC20. Etherscan seems ok towards my success transaction Txid: 0x3e0c39de20cda5f3ce34ae1b3bdde3fc6b76327566a3e9b4b50d3ba90e987846

But my target wallet account still displays balance: 0 AAA (without mistake with address via transfer ERC20 + wallet recreated already done to refresh it) and there is no more informations than that. Do you why and how i can retrieved my funds via https://temple.moonrabbit.com/wallet ?

Please can you someone came across this situation where Wallet balance was showing 0 howewer Etherscan showing the right number of balance ?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0x86e219be54468d33a934b5d40aa720aaacae7cb7#tokentxns the tokens are on this wallet. Check if it is your wallet, and if so, then the problem is with the wallet and not the transaction

Comment: See, I am using Etherscan and you are using Moonrabbit scan. Two different blockchains. On this Moonrabbit website they have info about how to bridge from Etherium to Moonrabbit at this link: https://lib.moonrabbit.com/_book/guides/Bridge.html . If you don't see the text, press CTRL+A.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your research Unfortunately not better i import my wallet into https://hole.moonrabbit.com/wallet/my-accounts and check of course that my address deposit of wallet is still the same of transaction AAA. Balance still 0 AAA : ( I'm going to search again how to do or understand the reason

Comment: Check out this link too, it could help you. You will need to install MataMask wallet for that https://lib.moonrabbit.com/_book/moon_rabbit_evm/Transfer-AAA-to-EVM.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried too but it didn't work with Metamask wallet because it's a different wallet of moon rabbit, then Secret recovery phrase of moon rabbit cannot build the same public address of my wallet. Perhaps one day later i'll know my mistake i done or not with this transfert AAA MXC -> https://hole.moonrabbit.com/wallet. But for the moment i haven't found any explanation because ERC20 tokens is normally used on moon rabbit network.